# installed nodejs from source, now errors

Tags: node.js

I'm on ubuntu. Installed node from ubuntu repository and everything was fine. Needed node-waf for one of the modules I was trying to install so I installed node to latest unstable from source. Now npm is broken. Want to go back to node 0.4 stable but when I uninstall the from source version i'm having problems.

1. Installed node from ubuntu repo
2. Installed node from source
3. Uninstalled node from source (`sudo make uninstall`, succeeds)
4. Runnning node results in: `bash: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory`

How can I get it to stop looking for node in that path?  Ubuntu repo node binaries still exist in `/usr/bin/node`. Running

```
cd /usr/bin ; ./node -v
```

works and spits out v0.4.12.

Running

```
cd /usr/bin ; node
```

errors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `bash(1)` shell will store the full pathname of an executable the first time it must search through the directories in the `PATH` environment variable. (It doesn't want to repeat this search every single time you type `ls` or `cat`, that'd be significantly slower than just looking up the exact pathname in a table.)

This process normally works without incident -- until you (re)move an executable between directories in the `PATH`.

New shells will not have trouble. Existing shells will need you to run `hash -r` to remove all the mappings from the built-in table. (Well, you can remove an individual entries using `hash -d node`, but re-populating the cache isn't horrible -- you do it every single time you start a shell -- and if there are multiple programs that are now missing, removing them all will save you from removing them individually.)